# Let $X$ be a set containing $n$ elements . Two subset $A$ and $B$ of $X$ are chosen at random . Find the probability that $ A \bigcup B = X $ .

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set containing $n$ elements . Two subset $A$ and $B$ of $X$ are chosen at random . Find the probability that $ A \bigcup B = X $ .

Solution given in the book :

for each $x_i \in X(i\le i \le n)$

We have four choices

(1) $x_i \in A $and $x_i \in B$

(2) $x_i b A$ and $x_i \notin B$

(3) $x_i \notin A$ and $x_i \in B$

(4) $x_i \notin A$ and $x_i \notin B$

$S$ be the sample space , $E$ be the event favourable

$n(E) = 4^n$

$n(S) = 3^n$

Hence the probability is $\frac{3^n}{4^n}$

But I want to do it by other method that is directly counting the number of sets that satisfy the union condition .

Total number of ways of selecting two sets at random is $2^n \cdot 2^n = 4^n$

But I facing problems counting the number of ways we can choose so that $A \bigcup B = X$ . It is becoming a complicated series which I am unable to prove in closed form to be equal to $3^n$ . 
Help me to prove it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $A\cup B = X$ is equivalent to $A^{C}\subseteq B.$ Suppose $X$ has $n$ elements; the number of such sets $B$ for a given $A$ is exactly $2^{|A|},$ since $A^{C}\subseteq B$ and the other $|A|$ elements can either be in $B$ or not. Thus the total number of pairs of subsets satisfying $A\cup B =X$ is given by $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{i}2^{i} = 3^{n},$$
where the $\binom{n}{i}$ term comes from the number of ways to pick a set with $i$ elements. Divide this by the total number of pairs of subsets, which is $2^{n}\cdot 2^{n} = 4^{n}.$

Comment: It's probably worth noting that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{i}2^{i} = 3^{n}$ follows from the binomial theorem: $(2+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{i}2^{i}1^{n-i}$.