# find the number of unordered pairs {A,B} of subsets of an n-element set X which satisfy the condition...[Read Full Que. Below]

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

find the number of unordered pairs {A,B} of subsets of an n-element set X which satisfy the condition:

- a) A ≠ B
- b) A ∪ B = X

**My Approach**

Solution for a: Was not able to think of one

Solution for b: Well considering the second part, A union B = X would mean that the only elements in X are A and B meaning there **2 pairs** in the b part (i.e {A,B} & {B,A})

Comment: I think this is one question, not two – you're meant to find the number of pairs that simultaneously satisfy both conditions. And I'm sure this questio  has been asked & answered on this website many times before.

Comment: okay that might be it but I didn't find any question even similar to this one

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591959/the-counting-problem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216984/finding-the-number-of-subset-pairs-of-a-set looks different, but it's equivalent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001365/choosing-pairs-of-subsets-so-that-their-union-is-s

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are *subsets* of $X$, not elements of $X$. Also it asks about *unordered* pairs. so $\{A, B\} = \{B, A\}$ would count as only one pair, not two.

Comment: So, Shlok, have you checked out those links?

Comment: Have you lost interest?

Comment: so sorry, I have had a series of exams, I had to study for them, I am probably going to check them afterwards but thanks a lot man!